# Find specific vector $x$, so that $x^\top A x = -x^\top x$ for a given symmetric and negative definite matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ is symmetric and negative definite, so there is an orthogonal matrix $T_1$, so that $T_1^\top A T_1 = D$ with $D$ containing the negative eigenvalues of $A$. Now I was looking for a vector (possibly depending on $T_1$) that satisfies the equation above.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a matrix exists if and only if $-1$ lies between the largest and smallest eigenvalues of $A$.

If $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then taking $x$ to be an eigenvector of $A$ (equivalently the column of $T_1$) corresponding to $\lambda = -1$ yields the desired outcome.

Otherwise, suppose that $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are eigenvalues of $A$ with $\lambda_1 < -1 < \lambda_2$. Let $x_i$ denote a length-1 eigenvector associated with $\lambda_i$ for $i = 1,2$. It suffices to take $x = \sqrt{1-t}x_1 + \sqrt{t}x_2$, where $t \in (0,1)$ satisfies 
$$
(1 - t)\lambda_1 + t\lambda_2 = -1 \implies t = \frac{-1 - \lambda_1}{\lambda_2 - \lambda_1}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $e_i$ be the eigenvectors of $A$ with corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda_i$. Let $x=\sum\limits_i c_ie_i$, then
$x^TAx=\left(\sum\limits_i c_ie_i\right)^T\left(\sum\limits_i \lambda_ic_ie_i\right)$ (as $Ae_i=\lambda_ie_i$) and $=\sum\limits_i \lambda_ic_i^2$ and should be $=-\sum\limits_i c_i^2$.
So $\sum\limits_i (\lambda_i+1)c_i^2=0$, but if we take $\forall i:\,-1<\lambda_i<0$ or $\forall i:\,\lambda_i<-1$ the equality can't hold.
Please correct me if I'm mistaken somewhere.